# Parentheses appearing as ASCII codes in FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create documents with certain text elements (as Cells) populated from a MySQL query.  One such field is $company.

Whenever the company name contains parentheses (ie 'Acme Fixings (UK) Ltd') the resulting PDF reads

```
Acme Fixings &#40;UK&#41; Ltd
```

I've tried using addslashes() to escape the parentheses to no avail.  Replacing the variable with a single-quoted string works fine.

I'm using the supplied Arial font.

Any clues?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Have you tried [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html-entity-decode)?

Comment: Thanks @Kolink - that works nicely. I'll get my head around why soon!

Comment: Comverted comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for some reason when inputting data into the database, parentheses were deemed hazardous and therefore encoded as HTML entities.

`html_entity_decode` reverses this process, resulting in parentheses.

Note that if you were outputting it to a browser and it "seemed" fine, it's because the browser decodes HTML entities. You should use View Source to see what is actually being output by the server.